# Why doesn't the modification of a property via an object method trigger a re-render?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

In this example both the method on the object and the function seem to modify the property of the object in the same way, both use assignment. But only the function call triggers the re-render. Why is that and is there a way to modify the method so it triggers the re-render as well? (without converting the property to a store)

-> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b0b927cdede8465ca9acf8d2a057dde8?version=3.44.2)

```html
<script>    
    class N {
        constructor() {
            this.numbers = [1,2,3]
        }   
        add(newN) {
            this.numbers = [...this.numbers, newN]
            console.log('numbers >', this.numbers)
        }
    }
    
    const numObj = new N()
    
    function add(newN) {
        numObj.numbers = [...numObj.numbers, newN]
        console.log('numbers >', numObj.numbers)
    }
    
</script>

{#each numObj.numbers as n}
 {n}
{/each}
<br><br>

<button on:click={_=> numObj.add(4)}>
    add number
</button>
via 'object method'<br>

<button on:click={_=> add(4)}>
    add number
</button>
via 'component function'<br>
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the `add` method on the object is an implementation detail of the object. State inside the object is not under Svelte's control. It doesn't know that calling `add` on the object modifies the `numbers` property of that object--you are assigning object state (`this.numbers`) inside that method, not Svelte component state. Theoretically, the Svelte compiler could be improved to detect this, but it would get unmanageable pretty quickly, especially when the object definition is outside the component.

However, when you call the component's `add` function, you are assigning to Svelte component state (`numObj.numbers`). This allows Svelte to pick up the assignment and trigger reactivity.